# Performance difference between .RemoveAll and .Where in C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a list of items and I want to iterate through a subset of them. Now, I am wondering if there is a performance impact difference between removing the unwanted items from the list and then loop through it; or simply filtering the list in the for loop.

Here is an example.

The RemoveAll approach:

```
list.RemoveAll(o => !someOtherList.Contains(o.Property));

foreach (var i in list)
{
}
```

The Where approach:

```
foreach (var i in list.Where(o => someOtherList.Contains(o.Property))
{
}
```

I understand that the first approach is actually going to manipulate what is in the list where as the second one won't. That doesn't really concern me. I am more concerned as to whether the filter in the second approach is applied for each iteration or whether C# is smart enough to create a subset and only loop through that subset (almost like the first approach with a temp variable).

Comment: If your question boils down to "how many times will `someOtherList.Contains` be invoked?", I strongly suspect the answer is the same for both samples.

Comment: Which one is faster ? Run both 1000 times and compute the average !

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: My question boils down to how many times list.Where will be invoked.

Comment: @user3185569 I will try that, just concerned that a simple example might not reflect the same impact as an example with much more complicated data structures; however, maybe that doesn't matter :)

Comment: @Johannes `Where` is executed once.. But the iterator stops each time it finds an element then executes the foreach body and then continue from where it left off.. Check my answer below. (As if you're leaving the index of the current search and then continuing to search from that point after the current item is processed in the foreach body) .. Does that make sense now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am more concerned as to whether the filter in the second approach is
>   applied for each iteration or whether C# is smart enough to create a
>   subset and only loop through that subset (almost like the first
>   approach with a temp variable)

Linq's `Where` uses [yield](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) in order to return the elements one at a time once requested.

So actually what is done in the second approach is:

1- Iterate through the list

2- Check if the Current element matches the condition **(Loops through someOtherList** unless it is a special lookup data structure eg. `HashSet`)

3- Once we find the first element return it

4- Execute the foreach body logic

5- Continue Searching from where we stopped at step 3

Meaning if you decided to break based on some condition inside the foreach block, then maybe not all the list may be scanned at that point which at some cases may give a performance boost on large lists.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to what others have said already, with raw performance  there wouldn't be neglectible difference if the loop operation is something like you showed.

However, first one requires to have a materialized List, while the latter works with IEnumerable. Also, for loop content to operate, first one needs to materialized first, until then the loop content is not started to be done. IOW  with a NOP loop both might take around 10 seconds to complete for some list and anotherList. When there is some work in the loop (likely), then the first one spends that 10 seconds before getting into the loop, then you need the time for processing in loop. The latter OTOH, would directly hit loop for each element it finds. If the loop content was a time consuming operation and moreover could be done asynch then latter would be a clear winner.